# android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" when i've already have ScrollView in the activity

Tags: android-layout

I have an activity with this Layouts structure: 
LinearLayout -> ScrollView -> TableLayout

Below the TableLayout i have EditText, which I want to be scrolled up when the keyboard is active.
So according to some reading I've made, i added:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to AndroidManifest.xml, to the relevant activity, and added a ScrollView wrapper to the activity.xml file, so the Layouts structures of the activity is now as follows:
ScrollView -> LinearLayout -> ScrollView -> TableLayout

The problem: The inner ScrollView is not working now... I guess the wrapping ScrollView is taking control when touched...

How can i solve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try to avoid the situation where a scrollview is somewhere in another scrollview. you can capture it, but this is not necessary. I got the some prob. but linearlayout>scrollview>tablelayout is enough for your problem. the inner scrollview is automatically adjusting to the right size. I would also recomment to add "stateVisible" to the inputMode option

Comment: But if i don't wrap the whole Activity with ScrollView, then the Activity won't get resized when the edittext clicked... Or am I wrong? I've tried without it, and the Activity didn't scrolled up with the keyboard - the keyboard just covered the EditText, again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was facing the same problem where the virtual keyboard was hiding EditTexts on my screen.
I introduced the following property for activity tag in the manifest file:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Also I needed to add following code in the activity's OnCreate function:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This solved the problem and it worked perfectly fine on all resolution emulators and samsung devices. It did fail, though, on Google Nexus S device and I could see the same problem again of virtual keyboard hiding the EditTexts.

Comment: This is at least a little bit wrong. According to [the documentation for windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) you can't set multiple `adjust` parameters (and it doesn't make sense anyway).

Comment: The documentation does not say that you can't set multiple values, just that the result is undefined so it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: After hours of searching this solved my `EditText` input lag problem (up to 5 seconds lag).  Thank you.

Comment: Seems this does the same as using just android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"