# android resize layout when keyboard appears

Tags: java, android

I would like to reposition layout when keyboard appears, for example when editing a text field, in order to get visibility on focused field. I tried windowSoftInputMode but I cannot get any difference. How to reach it? Thank you.

```
<activity 
            android:name="com.xxxx.projecte1.TabBar_Activity"      
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
           />
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is this line

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

in your code. This line tells the `Android` that your `Activity` will handle this 3 events on its own. If you remove this line, i believe you will have the desired effect.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) for the `configChanges` attribute.

Comment: @Jaume See this previous SO post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605076/androidwindowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-when-ive-already-have-scrollview-in). Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 11):

```
   <activity
        android:name=".WActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_two"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/appTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  worked for me

Comment: many thanks         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Answer (score 9):

#### For anyone else who might have a similar problem:

What fixed it in my case was just putting

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

into my activity's `onCreate` method.

Without any xml changes whatsoever, since those did not work for me whatsoever, but this worked right away like a charm. Although an xml solution seems nicer to me, even the same parameter did not work.

Sharing it since I did not find a quick and easy fix myself online.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out if you are modifying systemUiVisibility with flag View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN, you should be using setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE) to set the flag adjustResize. Do not forget to set android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on the root layout (under scrollview if you are using one).

Comment: `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` is deprecated